# How do you wire up jQuery when selector changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When I have an event handler set up through jQuery selecting DOM elements based on a data attribute (`$("input[data-action='enable']")`)

The code below duplicates what I am doing.  When the button is clicked, the  appropriate `callback` function is invoked and the data-action and value elements of the buttons are updated.  I was expecting to see that because the data-action value had changed that the click handler would toggle.  Is there a way to set this up so that this does happen, or do I need to manually set up the handler after the click event?

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" data-action="enable" value="enable" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" data-action="disable" value="disable" />

$("input[data-action='enable']").on("click", function() {
    var callback = function(context){
        context.val("disable");
        context.data("action", "disable");
    };
    ajaxCall(true, callback, $(this));
});

$("input[data-action='disable']").on("click", function() {
    var callback = function(context){
        context.val("enable");
        context.data("action", "enable");
    };
    ajaxCall(false, callback, $(this));
}); 

var ajaxCall = function(state, callback, context) {
    //would do an ajax call, and on success
    console.log(context.data("action"));
    callback(context);
};
```

Comment: The main problem is that you're binding to the result set of a jQuery selector, which returns an array of jQuery objects **at that specific time**. You will probably need to unbind your events after your ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the jQuery objects on which you are attaching handlers are not a "live" collection and don't reflect changes to the DOM. You'll need to use delegated events to handle this case as this will handle events on DOM elements which have been updated.

Also, the jQuery `data()` method does not update the underlying HTML, so you will need to change your selectors to a property which will be updated, such as the `value` attribute:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F77C8/3/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "input[value='enable']", function() {
    var callback = function(context){
        context.val("disable");
        context.data("action", "disable");
    };
    ajaxCall(true, callback, $(this));
});

$(document).on("click", "input[value='disable']", function() {
    var callback = function(context){
        context.val("enable");
        context.data("action", "enable");
    };
    ajaxCall(false, callback, $(this));
});
```

**EDIT:** You could also simplify this by making one event handler that is slightly more intelligent:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F77C8/4/)**

```
$("input").on("click", function() {
    var that = $(this),
        action = that.val() === 'enable' ? 'disable' : 'enable'
    ;

    ajaxCall(false, function(){
        that.val(action);
        that.data("action", action);
        console.log(action);
    });
});

var ajaxCall = function(state, callback) {
    //would do an ajax call, and on success
    callback();
};
```